# Replace (recode) values in a list

Tags: r

A have a list that has the following structure.

```
mylist=list(y~ A,
y ~ A+B,
y ~ A+B+C)
```

I want to replace (recode)  the `“y “`  with a `“z”`. my goal is

```
mylist=list(z~ A,
z ~ A+B,
z ~ A+B+C)
```

**Q: How to replace (recode) values in a list?**

I have tried this:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
  mylist[i] = mylist[i].replace('y','z')
```

is not working

Comment: This doesn't look like r code. Did you mean to tag with python perhaps?

Comment: @docendo discimus, ....Ah, that makes the sense. I got the example from a website in which is was sold  as an R code. That explains the mix up part of my trial. I was looking for an R solutions

Comment: So try to check answer i published. It's great text from AdvancedR to understand elements in list “If list x is a train carrying objects, then x[[5]] is the object in car
5; x[4:6] is a train of cars 4-6.”

Comment: Try `lapply(mylist, function(x) reformulate(as.character(terms(x))[3], "z"))` maybe in R

Comment: Thanks, @DavidArenburg. It works. But way is R putting e.g., "<environment: 0x16313cd4>" in the list. Where does that come from/way is R doing that? I hope you or someone else can explain way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `update` function is useful for formulas.

Just include a `.` to indicate any formula side to retain. So, for your problem the following is a quick one-liner.

`lapply(mylist, update, new = z~.)`

Comment: This seems like the best option. I didn't know `update` has an `update.formula` method

Answer (score 6):

I would alternatively suggest to use R built in formulas manipulation functionality. This allows us to operate on different terms of a fromula separately without using regex

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) reformulate(as.character(terms(x))[3], "z"))
# [[1]]
# z ~ A
# <environment: 0x59c6040>
#   
# [[2]]
# z ~ A + B
# <environment: 0x59c0308>
#   
# [[3]]
# z ~ A + B + C
# <environment: 0x59bb7b8>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a list of formulas as a start, you can convert the formulas to characters, use `gsub` to do the replacement and convert it back to formula. Use `env` parameter to specify the environment of the formulas to make sure they are the same as original list:

```
lapply(mylist, function(f) formula(gsub("y", "z", format(f)), env = .GlobalEnv))
# [[1]]
# z ~ A

# [[2]]
# z ~ A + B

# [[3]]
# z ~ A + B + C
```

To take care of the concern of @David Arenburg, so that the replacement of `y` will always happen on the left side of the formula, we can use a more restricted regular expression:

```
lapply(mylist, function(f) formula(gsub("y(\\s)?(?=~)", "z", format(f), perl = T), env = .GlobalEnv))

# [[1]]
# z ~ A

# [[2]]
# z ~ A + B

# [[3]]
# z ~ A + B + C
```

Comment: @ Psidom, this makes me smile, again. Thanks. I have one little question, way “env = .GlobalEnv” ? it helps me to understand. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this safe enough. What would happen for a formula such as `y ~ city + country`? Or how will you handle different names in the response variable? This regex isn't targeting just the response variable.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am assuming the case is very restricted to OP's description. But I consider the concern is valid here, just updated the answer to make it more general.

Comment: `env = .GlobalEnv` assign the environment of an object. Since the formula is generated in a function, by default, it will have an environment local to the function which is not the case in your original list. Assign the global environment to these formulas will make sure they are visible in the global R session.

Answer (score 2):

Just like expressions, formulas have replaceable parts.  So you could use `[[<-` to replace parts of the formula.  The `y` value is the second in the expression list, as `~` is a function and hence the first.

```
lapply(mylist, "[[<-", 2, as.name("z"))
# [[1]]
# z ~ A
#
# [[2]]
# z ~ A + B
#
# [[3]]
# z ~ A + B + C
```